# (2, 'No such file or directory') when trying to open a csv file on Django

Tags: python, django, csv, django-models, opencsv

I cannot for the life in me figure out why I keep getting this error. So I have a django module that is running the following code

```
c = open('file.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(c)
rows = []
rownum = 0
for row in reader:
    # Skip header
    if rownum != 0:
        rows.append(row)
    rownum += 1
c.close()
return rows
```

A few things to keep in mind. file.csv is in the same directory as the python file calling this function. I run this SAME code in the python interpreter, outside of the django environment and it works beautifully. I have tried rb and r, both don't work. I don't know why it doesn't work.

Is there something I am missing?

I am using python2.6

Comment: i am guessing when django runs your module it runs it from the app dir level whereas when you run it independently its run from inside the app dir. something like `./` vs `../` can you share what your project hierarchy is?

Comment: Have you tried to open the file with absolute path?

Comment: @SrikarAppal the name of the app is called backend and i have file.csv in that directory, as well as the file that is accessing it. im starting to think ill have to use STATIC_ROOT and put it with my other assets.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes i did :/

Comment: @barrigaj: did that work? If yes, you could use os.path.abspath(__file__).

Comment: @LaszloPapp Huh, works like magic, would you look at that. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Python wants to execute the file using the python  command, it doesn't look for the file in the py-Location like the interpreter does, but in some other folder (don't know in which one exactly). So how to solve this problem: If you want to keep the independency of no fixed file path, use this code:

```
import os
workpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) #Returns the Path your .py file is in
c = open(os.path.join(workpath, 'file.csv'), 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(c)
rows = []
rownum = 0
for row in reader:
    # Skip header
    if rownum != 0:
        rows.append(row)
    rownum += 1
c.close()
return rows
```

Now just put (or keep) the .csv file in the same folder as the main .py-Script - and you're done!
(Script is untested, tell me if I made it not work out of some stupidness)

Comment: I used os.path.abspath like in your example and it works! Thanks to @Laszlo Papp

Comment: You should use `os.path.join` instead of manually combining strings to create the path.